# Can't log into Twitter from Android app. TwitterException on getting the Email

Tags: java, android, twitter

I have the necessary key and secret, but somehow I'm getting

> com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException: Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

I have an email provided with my twitter account, I also read that because I have activated my Twitter via phone number this will not be supplied. If so how do we get these email addresses when they did activate via phone number?

*keys are being used by other platforms and are ok.

** Update, I have signed in with my old twitter account without a phone number in it. It did log in successfully.

Question would be how to fetch the email if they do have the phone number activated?

Comment: Post your code that is most welcome besides explanations.

Comment: Just like i said, this is working with a different Twitter account. Codes are all the same documentation instruction. Only my other account can't log in to this.

Comment: Are you sure that **Request email addresses from users**  check box now appeared in your permission tab ? **If yes** you won't do anything specially rather than requesting for email with same code .

Comment: YES , like I said one account is working  and the other(said to be phone activated) isn't working.

Comment: Have you done it **#mikey** ?

Comment: not yet, just showed a Toast instead(no luck yet)

Answer (score 0):

Upon the exception in your query, It seems you have requested for the `email_id` of your a/c .

> Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be
>   whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, please [use this form](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform).
>
> Once whitelisted, the “Request email addresses from users” checkbox
>   will be available under your app permissions on [apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com/).
>   Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL fields will also be
>   available under settings which are required for email access. If
>   enabled, users will be informed via the [oauth/authorize](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize) dialog
>   that your app can access their email address.

**Note**

Your app will need to regenerate the user access tokens for previously authenticated users to access their email address.

After doing all these follow the [tuts](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/request-user-email-address.html) to fetch the `email_id`

```
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();

authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<String> result) {
        // Do something with the result, which provides the email address
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
      // Do something on failure
    }
});
```

Comment: we already have that and we are approved. I have tested another Twitter account without a phone number in it. It worked!